# Maximizing Time of Flight in Projectile Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile, calculus

Is (*or How is*) it possible to maximize the **time of flight** of projectile subject to the following conditions?

Given :

1. Fixed horizontal range
2. Interval in which **velocity** lies

For example, let the range be 100 feet. The velocity of projectile lies in the closed interval **[40√2,80]$\frac{ft}{s}$**. Given acceleration due to gravity is **32$\frac{ft}{s^2}$**. Then, ignoring frictional forces (*more precisely, viscous drag*) what will be the maximum value of time of flight of projectile?

Comment: If you want to maximize the flight time then that's equivalent to maximizing the y-component of the initial velocity, isn't it?

Comment: Choose the maximum velocity in the allowed range. This must be $\ge \sqrt{4gR}$ where $R$ is range. For this velocity, the launch angle $\theta$ must be such that $R=\frac{v^2}{g}\sin2\theta$. The maximum time of flight is then $T=\frac{2v}{g}\sin\theta$.

Comment: For recommendations of other sites see [my question was closed on phys se - can you recommend me another internet site?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/) You might like to try http://physics.qandaexchange.com. – sammy gerbil 35 secs ago   edit

Answer (score 1):

The range is given by

$$R(v_0,\theta_0)=\frac{v_0^2\sin2\theta_0}g$$

The flight time is given by:

$$\tau(v_0,\theta_0)=\frac{2v_0\sin\theta_0}g$$

Maximum point is given by:

$$\nabla\tau(v_0,\theta_0)=0$$

Our constrain here is that $R$ is fixed. so $\lambda R$ is also fixed. So adding it to $\tau(v_0,\theta_0)$ doesn't alter $\nabla\tau(v_0,\theta_0)$.

Lagrange has invented this trick. That $\lambda$ is the equalizing constant which corrects the units, scaling, etc. Now let's use is.

$$\nabla(\tau(v_0,\theta_0)+\lambda R)=0$$

$$\nabla(\frac{2v_0\sin\theta_0}g+\lambda\frac{v_0^2\sin2\theta_0}g)=0$$

$$\nabla(2v_0\sin\theta_0+\lambda v_0^2\sin2\theta_0)=0$$

$$(\sin\theta_0+\lambda v_0 \sin2\theta_0,\cos\theta_0+\lambda v_0\cos2\theta_0)=0$$

Gives,

$$-\lambda v_0=\frac1{2\cos\theta_0}\ \ ,\ \ \cos\theta_0=-\lambda v_0\cos2\theta_0$$

$$\sin^2\theta_0+\cos^2\theta_0=1\ \ , \ \ v_0=-\frac1{2\lambda\cos\theta_0}$$

Considering $L_- \le v_0 \le L_+$, we get,

$$-\frac1{2\lambda L_+}\le \cos\theta_0 \le -\frac1{2\lambda L_-}$$

So $\theta_0$ can be anything as long as it satisfies the condition above, and in the upper line, we have $v_0$ as a function of $\theta_0$. So everything is solved.

Except one thing, I haven't studied how to find $\lambda$ yet. :D So sorry. Others familiar with Lagrange's method may help me complete my answer.

Comment: I don't think that it should be necessary to use Lagrangian multipliers to get the answer. See my comment above. Maximizing flight time is equivalent to maximizing the y-component of the initial velocity subject to the constraint that the range is 100 feet. This should be a relatively easy back-of-the-envelope calculation.

Comment: I found the method. let me finish it and see if our answers agree. then you must be right.

Answer (score -1):

Use the trajectory equation for uniform acceleration and take the derivative set to zero to find critical points. Use maximum. Usually theta is 45 ignoring draft.

Comment: Since velocity is constrained here, and range is fixed, the angle may be something other than 45.

Comment: Hence my suggestion of taking the derivative to find max t within the velocity domain. Those constraints aren't well defined, are they two possible vector magnitudes or x and y components? And sorry but without drag the angle 45 is accepted as being the optimal trajectory angle. Again the solution is the derivative to find the max.

Comment: @ShuddaBeenCodin - 45 degrees is the angle for the maximum distance (in the absence of air drag). The question asks for the angle for the maximum time of flight with certain constraints, not for the angle of maximum distance.

Comment: Ok, I thought I made it clear that the solution is to find the max critical point using the derivative of the trajectory set to zero. Sorry if I was unclear.